# How to restore a over-written built-in function in Julia

Tags: julia

The question may apply for other languages, too.

If I use a built-in function name as a variable name,
I can restore the function by doing:

```
all = 123
all = Base.all
```

But If I define, for example, a custom function sum() and then I do,

```
sum = Base.sum
```

I got an error saying "invalid redefinition of constant sum"

Is there a way to restore a built-in function if I over-wrote it? Or is that impossible by design?

Comment: That would be the correct way to do it, but as you see, you can't redefine variables like that if they are functions, so no, I don't think you can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example, you could just redefine `sum` as `Base.sum`:

`sum(x) = Base.sum(x)`

Is that what you would like?

NB. this may not "overwrite" your definition of sum. If it uses type parameters (e.g. `sum(x::Vector)` it may still be dispatched in preference to the general `sum(x)`, in which case you would need to repeat the above for those specific methods.

Comment: What to do if I've redefined pi?

Answer (score 1):

If this is simply a problem for you when you are working in the REPL, and you don't mind losing all your other definitions, you could do `workspace()` to reset `Main`.

Comment: Thanks! this is not exactly what I asked for, but is useful when I am learning basics of Julia and only trying to mess with the default namespace.

Comment: If you really need to overwrite the definition for a section of code, could you put that code into a module, so that it only affects the code in that module, and outside of the module you'd see the normal definition of the function?